# Send image generated with node-gd to client

Tags: node.js, express, image-processing

EDIT: the solution is to use

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
res.end(data, 'binary').
```

---

I am trying to dynamically generate images using node-gd. My application is node.js/express.

This code successfully generates an image:

```
    //create image
    var gd = require('node-gd');
    var img = gd.createSync(200, 80);
    img.colorAllocate(0, 255, 0);

    img.savePng('../test.png', 0, function(error) {
      if (error) throw error;
      img.destroy();
    })
```

But it saves the image to a file. I don't necessarily want to keep the generated images, just send it to the client.

I was hoping I could just do

```
res.send(img);
```

But that just returns an object with metadata about the image.

EDIT:
Attempt at outputting the pointer:

```
    //create image
    var gd = require('node-gd');
    var img = gd.createSync(200, 80);
    img.colorAllocate(0, 255, 0);

    var imageData = img.pngPtr();
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    console.log(imageData);
    res.send(imageData);
```

In my browser I get:

The image “URLHERE” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

The file isn't empty, it's like 138 bytes, where the actual image is like 2kb.

if I log the PNG data (I didn't expect it to be readable, but still):

```
PNG

IHDRÈPf£¨óPLTEÿ4^À¨     pHYsÄÄ+IDATHc`£`Q0
FÁ( ½1üñIEND®B`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would Express's [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) method work for you?

`res.sendFile('/path/to/image.png')`

Comment: Possibly, trying to iron out the details right now. But what if multiple people download a file at the same time? And does saving it to the disk affect performance? It seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Ideally it sounds like you want to create a buffer in memory and just serve that. I briefly looked over the node-gd api and didn't see any method for doing so, so that's why I thought res.sendFile would be your easiest bet.

Comment: Looks like maybe you could use node-gd's pointer functions:

https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd/blob/stable/docs/index.md#saving-graphic-images

Comment: Cool, I can do it this way then. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wow, we posted at the same time, I'll give that a look over later too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pointer` ( the buffer ) of the image via the API.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
res.send( img.pngPtr() );
```

You can read more about the functions in the [official documentation](https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd/blob/stable/docs/index.md#saving-graphic-images)

Comment: That definitely looks right, but I'm still having issues and don't see anything in the docs that really implies otherwise. I updated my post above with my findings

Comment: Opened an issue with the author and they said to use "res.end(data, 'binary')", which seems to solve the problem

Comment: @stackers - please add this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

send it as a binary:

```
res.write(buffer,'binary');
res.end(null, 'binary');
```

The imageptr() generated.

To generate the binary refer this https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd/blob/stable/docs/index.md#saving-graphic-images

I used:

var jpgImageData = img.jpegPtr(0);